# Using djnz to make a loop in 8051 assembly language

Tags: microprocessor, assembly, 8051

To program 8051 using djnz loop I know that if we give `r0` a number the loop will be executed accordingly. For example:

```
Mov r0,#50
Back: instructions
Djnz r0,back
```

The loop will be executed 50 times.

But if I want to place `djnz` in the beginning should I initialize `r0` as 51 to make the loop instructions skipped 50 times?

For example:

```
Ex: djnz r0, skip
instructions 
Skip: end
```

I want to pass the instructions 50 times for an interrupt ISR.  So can you tell me which number I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really quite simple. the `djnz` instruction decrements the value of a register by one and then executes the jump if the result was nonzero. So, yes, if you want to skip a block of code 50 times, you need to set the register value to 51 to start with.

Note that if the register value is 1, the decrement will produce a result of 0 and the jump will NOT be taken. Therefore, in order to skip the code once, you need to start with a value of 2.

Note also that if the register is 0 to start with, the decrement will result in a value of 255, and the jump WILL be taken.